# ballerina.io SQL LIKE statement

Tags: sql, mariadb, where-clause, sql-like, ballerina

i am currently trying to execute the following SQL statement in ballerina.io against a MariaDB.

Plan SQL:

```
select * FROM testDB where test LIKE '%BA%';
```

I get a result set with all data.

ballerina.io:

```
var selectRet = testDB->select("select * FROM testDB where test LIKE '%?%'", testREC, "BA");
```

I get an empty result set.

versions:
ballerina --version
jBallerina 1.1.2
Language specification 2019R3
Ballerina tool 0.8.0

Is it possible to make a SQL statement with LIKE in ballerina.io?

Many greetings,
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is passed to the query as a separate literal string, not as some kind of template variable. To surround it with wildcards, you need to use `concat()` in the query:

```
var selectRet = testDB->select(
    "select * FROM testDB where test like concat('%', ?, '%')", 
    testREC, 
    "BA"
);
```

Or just concatenate the wildcards in your code (this looks a bit cleaner to me):

```
var selectRet = testDB->select(
    "select * FROM testDB where test like ?", 
    testREC, 
    "%BA%"
);
```